# Debug draw physics shapes not drawing after i upgraded to cocos2d 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I am custom debug- drawing physics shapes in my game. After I upgraded to cocos2d 2.0, iOS 5 , i got some errors which indicated me to replace cccolor4f, glpushmatrix etc. But I cant find an alternative for glscalef function. I get an error on this function call.

Here's my code:

```
   [super draw];

   kmGLPushMatrix();
{

   // No idea what will replace this one
  //    glScalef(PTM_RATIO, PTM_RATIO,0.f);

  ccDrawColor4F(0.f, 1.f, 0.f, 1.f);

  [physicsshapeobject debugdraw]; // This calls the function below for different shapes

 }
    kmGLPopMatrix();

 ccDrawColor4F(1.f, 1.f, 0.f, 1.f);
 ccPointSize(10.f);
 //drawPoint(collisionAt_);
 ccPointSize(1.f);
 }

 -(void) debugDraw{

if(polygonShape != NULL){

CGPoint boxPt = ccpFromB2Vec(shapeTransform->p, NO);

CGPoint p1 = ccpAdd(boxPt,ccpFromB2Vec(polygonShape->m_vertices[0], NO));
CGPoint p2 = ccpAdd(boxPt,ccpFromB2Vec(polygonShape->m_vertices[1], NO));
CGPoint p3 = ccpAdd(boxPt,ccpFromB2Vec(polygonShape->m_vertices[2], NO));
CGPoint p4 = ccpAdd(boxPt,ccpFromB2Vec(polygonShape->m_vertices[3], NO));
ccVertex2F v1;
ccVertex2F v2;
ccVertex2F v3;
ccVertex2F v4;

v1.x = p1.x;
v1.y = p1.y;

v2.x = p2.x;
v2.y = p2.y;

v3.x = p3.x;
v3.y = p3.y;

v4.x = p4.x;
v4.y = p4.y;

ccQuad2 quad = (ccQuad2){
  v1,
  v2,
  v3,
  v4,
};
ccDrawColor4F(1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
ccDrawPoly((CGPoint*)&quad, 4, YES);

}
 }
```

What could be the reason of the shapes not drawing? What is the alternative to glscalef in cocos2d 2.0?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

now Cocos2D 3.0 is deeply integrated with Chipmunk2D physics engine. So if you use the default `CCPhysicsNode` you can enable debug draw by simply calling `setDebugDraw` like this:

```
_physicsWorld = [CCPhysicsNode node];
_physicsWorld.gravity = ccp(0,0);
_physicsWorld.debugDraw = YES;
_physicsWorld.collisionDelegate = self;
[self addChild:_physicsWorld];
```